# Unity 3d List<> do not work in android, but works fine in Unity Editor

Tags: c#, android, list, unity-game-engine

I am making a `List` of `GameObjects` called checkpoints. At the start, all of the `GameObjects` are set to inactive in the editor. When the player starts an event, `checkpoint`s get activated one by one in a sequence. When a vehicle triggers a `checkpoint`, the next `checkpoint` gets activated. Everything works fine in Unity Play Mode without any error or warning.

However, in the Android build, the following statement `checkPoints[currentCheckPoint].SetActive(true);` doesn't work and all the code after it does not get executed.  I'm only posting relevant code because the full script is a bit lengthy.

```
public List<GameObject> checkPoints;

static int tottalCheckPoints = 0;
int currentCheckPoint = 0;

private void Start()
{
    tottalCheckPoints = transform.childCount;
    for (int i = 0; i < tottalCheckPoints; i++)
    {
        if (transform.GetChild(i).tag == "CheckPoint" || transform.GetChild(i).tag == "FinaleCheckPoint")
        {
            checkPoints.Add(transform.GetChild(i).gameObject);
        }
    }
}

public void CheckPointTriggered()
{
    if (currentCheckPoint < tottalCheckPoints)
    {
        checkPoints[currentCheckPoint].SetActive(true); /*<------ that statement and all the statements after that doesn't get executed in android build.*/
        currentCheckPoint++;
    }
}
```

I used text logging in Android by printing specific text on screen after every statement to see from where the code stops working and found that the following statement doesn't get executed (or any other statement after that). `checkPoints[currentCheckPoint].SetActive(true);`

I am using latest version of Unity 2018.1.4.f1.

Comment: I see that `List<GameObject> checkPoints` is declared but I don't see it initialized anywhere in the code you provided...

Comment: Sir It do gets initialized in Start() method, Last statement in Start() gets all child of the parent object and store it in a list. That works fine 100% in editor I can see the children in publicly exposed variable (List<>) in inspector.

Comment: Yeah I'm not sure what I was thinking. I looked at it quickly and missed that it was a `public` field exposed to the editor.

Comment: Does the Android build give any error messages?

Comment: Yes I have made many builds all day and all was successful. No error in build at all.

Comment: Put `Debug.Log` before and after `SetActive` and tell us which one is showing and which one is not.

Comment: I did put Debug.Log before and after SetActive().  It get executed before but not after.

Answer (score 0):

Couple things to consider here.

```
static int tottalCheckPoints = 0; int currentCheckPoint = 0;

private void Start() {
    tottalCheckPoints = transform.childCount;
    for (int i = 0; i < tottalCheckPoints; i++)
    {
        if (transform.GetChild(i).tag == "CheckPoint" || transform.GetChild(i).tag == "FinaleCheckPoint")
        {
            checkPoints.Add(transform.GetChild(i).gameObject);
        }
    } }
```

You are setting the total number of checkpoints to the total number of children in the current gameobject.  Then you are adding checkpoints only if they have the tag "CheckPoint" or "FinaleCheckPoint".

This means that your totalCheckPoints could be a higher number than your CheckPoint list length.  It will only match if every child has one of those two tags.

```
if (currentCheckPoint < tottalCheckPoints)
{
    checkPoints[currentCheckPoint].SetActive(true); /*<------ that statement and all the statements after that doesn't get executed in android build.*/
    currentCheckPoint++;
}
```

Here, check the value of currentCheckPoint and tottalCheckPoints and see if they make sense. You made tottalCheckPoints static, so it could be getting changed elsewhere when you don't mean it to.

Without seeing more detail it's hard to say anything more.  When you are in editor mode you may have items in your scene that don't exist in your built version (maybe a different scene is loaded for example), which would cause this problem but we can't tell that here.

Comment: That parent only contains Check Points as children nothing else. Last child has FinaleCheckPoint tag and all other have CheckPoint Tag.

Comment: 1) Yes I am getting all the children of the parent. All the children in that parent GameObject is only checkpoints. So that specific part is not even a issue it is working 100% fine, In Unity and also in android build. 2) Nothing is accessed or changed by any other script. 3) Every thing working fine in unity editor, so if it works in unity editor why it is not working in android build? I also made sure that i am building correct scene for android.

Answer (score 0):

Theres zero reasons for this to work in windows build and not work in android build, but doing stuff in OnValidate was the number one reason for me builds failed to wo. Is the windows build working? My bet would be on NO, and my bet on the reason is 'you are doing stuff in OnValidate() that shouldn't be done there. Its so conveinient that before I learned I've had several projects with deployment delayed due to this. OnValidate is triggered when the scene starts within the editor, BY THE EDITOR, but is not called ever in the build, ever . Please check that and upvote if it helped.

In some cases I just added OnValidate() calls to Start() and that solved the issue

Answer (score 0):

Finlay, Issue is solved. There was some problem with Unity editor or my computer I don't know. I had restarted Unity many times, issue was not solved. I usually don't shutdown my computer often. So today I have restarted my computer and build again and every thing started working in the build too.